# How do you determine that the series solution to the hermite differential equation is not square integrable?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, harmonic-oscillator, normalization

When solving the Schrodinger equation of the harmonic oscillator in one dimension you encounter the hermite differential equation:

\begin{equation}
\left[\frac{d^{2}H}{d\xi^{2}}-2\xi\frac{d H}{d \xi }+\left(\lambda-1\right) H\right]e^{-\xi^{2}/2}=0.
\end{equation}

We can find a solution to this equation in the form of a series:

\begin{equation}
       H(\xi)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n}\xi^{n} \
 \end{equation}

with the following coefficients:
\begin{equation}
     a_{n+2}=\frac{\left[2n-\left(\lambda-1\right)\right]a_{n}}{(n+2)(n+1)}.
     \label{coefficient_série}
 \end{equation}
Since we look for a square integrable solution we usually truncate the series by imposing that $\lambda=2n+1$. My question is how do you assess that$\langle\psi|\psi\rangle$ diverges, with $\psi$= $H(\xi)e^{-\frac{\xi^2}{2}}$?

Usually in textbooks it's said that $H(\xi)$ behave assymptotically for large $\xi$ as $e^{\xi^2}$. Does someone as the actual derivation of this behaviour?
From my understanding the only thing we can say is that for large value of $n$ we have:

\begin{equation}
     \frac{a_ {n+2}}{a_{n}} \simeq \frac{2}{n}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
     e^{\xi^{2}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\xi^{2n}}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_{n}\xi^{2n}
 \end{equation}

\begin{equation}
     \left|\frac{c_{n+1}}{c_{n}}\right|=\frac{n!}{(n+1)!}=\frac{1}{n+1}.
 \end{equation}

So we see that both series are convergent with an infinite radius of convergence and that in both series the coefficients decreases in $\frac{1}{n}$. How is it sufficient to say that $H(\xi)$ behave as $e^{\xi^2}$ when $\xi$ goes to infinity?

Comment: This is an interesting question to me too. I have always heard that the power series method of solution for the harmonic oscillator lacks rigor and that the correct way to handle the problem is through Sturm-Liouville theory rather than make the $e^{-\xi^2}$ ansatz. I have never looked into the matter more though.

Comment: I think this is commented on in Galindo & Pascual's book (IIRC, they point to an appendix which discusses some properties of confluent hypergeometric functions).

Answer (score 3):

For large $n$,
$$\frac{a_{n+2}}{a_{n}}\approx\frac{2}{n}$$
means
$$a_n\approx\frac{C}{(n/2)!}$$
for some constant $C$ and therefore
$$H(\xi)\approx C\sum_n \frac{1}{(n/2)!} \xi^n\approx C\sum_l\frac{1}{l!}\xi^{2l}\approx C\exp(\xi^2)$$

Edit: To make this rigorous, it's enough to get a lower bound $H(\xi)\ge\epsilon \exp(\xi^2)$ for some $\epsilon>0$ and large enough $\xi$.  That's enough to make the solution non-square-integrable.

Comment: So truncating the series ensures that $H(\xi)$ is a polynomial and hence does not blow up faster than $e^{-\xi^2}$ goes to zero?

Comment: @AlbertusMagnus  indeed it explains why you have to truncate the series since multiplying $H(\xi)$ by $exp(-\frac{\xi^{2}}{2})$ is like  $Cexp(\xi^{2})exp(-\frac{\xi^{2}}{2})=Cexp(\frac{\xi^{2}}{2})$ and this function is obviously not square integrable.